# Handling uploaded files in Django

Tags: django, file-upload, django-file-upload

I am getting a file from user which is of xlsx or CSV format.
I am saving the data of the files into my database using "django-excel".
But after I perform `request.FILES['file'].save_to_database()` then if I try to access the uploaded file's contents using `request.FILES['file']` again then I am unable to access them.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML form have this attribute?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

You need this 'enctype' to access the request.FILES

Comment: Yes it does , i am able to access the files but once I open the files and use them then i am unable to reuse them. lets say a user uploaded the file named foo.xlsx , I open the sheet and take out some values . then I try to apply the same operation request.FILES['file'].save_to_database() which fails .